# How to create a custom Bubble Slider in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

How can I create a custom bubble slider with this exact bubble icon as in the picture?

Also, I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-range-slider library but there were some installation issues with that library so couldn't use it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-range-slider

Comment: @Siraj will I be able to use a bubble icon like mine from this library?

Comment: It seems `rn-range-slider` is only availble library but how about using any normal slider with tooltip from react-native-elements? I mean customize it to pop over your slider

Comment: @JaydeepGalani but how can tooltip be fixed on moving slider?